# How do I connect to a WiFi network using wicd?

Tags: wireless, wicd, wpa2, wpa-supplicant

I am not able to connect to a WiFi network using wicd. My wicd log file is as

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6423667/

The configuration I must use is as shown here -> http://www.depts.ttu.edu/ithelpcentral/solutions/wireless/

My /etc/wicd/wireless-settings.conf file contains the below settings among other things.

```
[essid:TTUnet]
afterscript = None
dhcphostname = chrysophylax
bssid = 00:24:14:10:BF:21
postdisconnectscript = None
domain = TTU
dns_domain = None
gateway = None
use_global_dns = 0
password = ERAIDER_CLEARTEXTPASSWORD
encryption = True
ip = None
beforescript = None
hidden = False
channel = 6
mode = Master
ca_cert = None
never = 0
netmask = None
usedhcphostname = 0
predisconnectscript = None
identity = ERAIDER_USERNAME
enctype = peap-tkip
dns3 = None
dns2 = None
search_domain = None
use_settings_globally = 1
use_static_dns = 0
encryption_method = WPA2
essid = TTUnet
automatic = 1
dns1 = None
```

Is this configuration wrong? Why does my authentication keep failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new encryption template for TTUnet

```
name = TTUnetEncryption
author = lordloh
version = 1
require identity *Username password *Password
protected password *Password
-----
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={ 
   ssid="$_ESSID" 
   proto=RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP 
   eap=PEAP
   phase1="peaplabel=0" 
   phase2="autheap=MSCHAPV2" 
   identity="$_IDENTITY" 
   password="$_PASSWORD" 
   priority=1 
}
```

placed this in `/etc/wicd/encryption/templates/` and activated it in `/etc/wicd/encryption/templates/active`.

This let me connect to the network. However, I think I shall ditch `wicd` as it disconnects the wired network while connecting to wireless networks.